# How to display list data using indexing instead of property name in angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to display data from list coming from database.But I don't want to give name of property to display data as I am trying to reuse Markup. 
Below is my code.

```
<div class="card card-design" *ngFor="let val of listData; let i = index">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label class="CardViewText CardViewHeaderFont marginZero">{{val[0]}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

like above I want to bind column value using index instead of property name. I am not able to achieve. Can anyone please help me for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you has an object, and you want know the "keys", you can use JSON.stringify (convert to string the obj) + replace (to remove specials character but not ":" and ",")+split (create an array)+ map (each element key:value, using split we get only the key. puff

```
getOrderedKeys(obj):string[]
{
  return JSON.stringify(obj)
    .replace(/[&\/\\#+()$~%.'"*?<>{}]/g,'')
    .split(',')
    .map(x=>x.split(':')[0]);
}
```

So, when you has this.listData

```
this.keys=this.getOrderedKeys(this.listData[0])
//and
<div class="card card-design" *ngFor="let val of listData; let i = index">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label class="CardViewText CardViewHeaderFont marginZero">{{val[keys[0]]}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use index then you have to use your array `listData`, like:

```
<div class="card card-design" *ngFor="let val of listData; let i = index">
  <div class="card-body">
    <label class="CardViewText CardViewHeaderFont marginZero">{{listData[i]}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```